# Java - The Most Efficient Way to Load Text From Website?

Tags: java, url, web

I have a question for you all. I am going for speed, and I need to use this method a lot, so the more efficient this method is, the better.

My code:

```
private void method(final String name) {
    final URL url = new URL("http://www.somewebsite.com/blah.php?name=" + name);
    final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openConnection().getInputStream()));
    final String totalText = in.readLine();
    in.close();
    //other stuff using the totalText variable
}
```

This method **works**, but I am asking if there is a *more* efficient way for this to work.

Important Notes Concerning the code I am reading:

- The **entire** source code from the website is only **one** line long.
- There are **no** HTML tags with the website code. It is all **raw** text.

Comment: I wonder ... would `totalText = in.readLine();` work? Then I would just remove the `inputLine` variable and the `while` loop?

Comment: If you are sure that it will always be 1 line, yes. But shouldnt speed up that much

Comment: EVERYONE: I have revised my code.

Comment: @JavaCoder-1337 i have edited my code... see it... see the First point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** If its **one line of code**, as you have changed you question then do the following...
                Use Only `InputStream` and `Scanner`.

```
final URL url = new URL("http://www.somewebsite.com/blah.php?name=" + name);
InputStream i = url.openStream();
Scanner scan = new Scanner(i);
final String totalText = scan.nextLine();
```

**2.** If mulitple lines then, I will advice you **not to create a String object every time**, cause **creating Object on the Heap is expensive.**

These **2 below lines will create a lot of String object** on the heap.

`((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)`

`totalText += inputLine;`

**Use** `StringBuilder` which is **Mutable**, and at the end assign it to the String reference using `toString()` method.

**Eg:**

```
StringBuilder totalText;
   String ftotal;

   while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    totalText.append(inputLine);
}


   ftotal = totalText.toString();
```

Comment: From his question: The entire source code from the website is only one line long

Comment: @JavaCoder-1337 then why are you using the while loop? Just write totalText=in.readLine()

Comment: @JavaCoder-1337 i have edited my code... see it... see the First point

Comment: Thanks. What about closing the scanner? Is this necessary?

Comment: What about `scan.close()`? Are these necessary?

Comment: After running some tests, my code proves to be faster than yours. Thanks anyway!